# React sorted list - click events fired incorrectly

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of services sorted based on checked/unchecked values. So unchecked goes at the top of the list and checked goes at the bottom. After saving the list, the sorting function runs again in a render function.

The sorting function is correct, however, on the second render, the behavior is very strange. When some selected and saved, selecting checkbox again behaves like those "filtered down" element are still in the list (list render is correct, but events are fired with "shift" in render)

Not sure if code example would be self-explanatory, that's why I'm attaching short gif of the problem

[image]

```js
  const content = serviceContext.getList
    .sort((a, b) => {
      // show unselected at top of list
      if (activeNode !== 'DEFAULT') {
        const aChecked = serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds.includes(a.service_id);
        const bChecked = serviceContext.nodeListArrayIds.includes(b.service_id);

        return aChecked - bChecked;
      }

      return -1;
    })
```

List elements are keyed (uniqully)

```js
          <tbody>
            {content &&
              content.map((row, idx) => (
                <tr key={idx}>
                  {row &&
                    row.map((col, i) => (
                      <td key={`${idx}_${i}`}>
                        <AdminListCol col={col} callback={colCallback} />
                      </td>
                    ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
```

Comment: Index as a key is probably the cause since you're removing the elements as well. Take something else as unique key. Like maybe `service_id` or whatever unique id you have.

Comment: `events are fired with "shift" in render` what do you mean? I struggle to understand the question. But as @LakshyaThakur pointed out: your `key` values are useless. Both `<tr key={idx}>` and `<td key={`${idx}_${i}`}>` will mess up your UI when the position of any of your items will ever change. Take `col_title` and `service_name` as keys (assuming you have no duplicated columnbs and no duplicated services in your list)

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Thank you, you are right. Despite idx keys were unique, this somehow broke React logic. I even displayed data-id attributes on rows/cols, and they were correct, but when clicking row (after re-sorting lists), it showed the wrong id on callbacks. Never had problems using idx's for past 3 years but this specific case is something new :)

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Feel free to post an answer, will mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the index of an element as a key.

Check out [this](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) blog post for more explanation.